# How would I get the Min and Max scores of the bowlers without using the built in function in c#

Tags: c#, max, min

I am stuck on how to get the Minimum and Maximum value of scores since we are not allowed to use the built-in function for our assignment, I got the average working good and those are the only missing piece of my assignment.

```
double game average = 0
for (int gameCounter = 1; gameCounter < gameScores.Length + 1; gameCounter++)
    {
        gameAverage += (gameScores[gameCounter - 1] / NUMBER_OF_GAMES);
    }
```

Comment: It is often easier to loop through arrays with code like `foreach (var score in gameScores)` that trying to add and subtract indexes like you are doing.

Comment: I cant believe your teacher is letting you use `goto`...

Comment: Suppose I handed you a bowling score card and asked you to determine the minimum and maximum values. Describe **carefully** how you would do so *without using a computer*. If you can do that, then you can describe how a computer should do it.

Comment: While we are looking at your code: today would be a great day to get into good habits so you don't have to break them later. (1) We do not use SHOUTING_SNAKE_FORM in C#.  That should be `GameCount` or `NumberOfGames`.  (2) it is very strange to set up a loop where the counter is off by one, and then subtract one from it to correct that.  The more normal thing to do would be to loop from 0 to length, not from 1 to length + 1 and then subtract 1 from the index.

Comment: (3) your code looks wrong. I assume that gamescores[i] is an int and number of games is an int, but int divided by int is int, not double. The more usual solution would be to compute the sum first, then convert the sum to double, then to divide the sum by the number of games, to get an accurate double. What you are doing now is *rounding before adding*, and rounding before adding means that you are adding up *wrong* values, so the sum will also be wrong, and therefore also the average will be wrong.

Comment: Speaking of NUMBER_OF_GAMES -- why do you have NUMBER_OF_GAMES at all? if NUMBER_OF_GAMES is the same as gameScores.Length then you don't need NUMBER_OF_GAMES in the calculation at all; just divide by gameScores.Length.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the min and max values as the first value and compare the next value with the current value

```
double gameMin = Double.MaxValue;
double gameMax = Double.MinValue;
for (int gameCounter = 1; gameCounter < gameScores.Length + 1; gameCounter++)
{
  gameMin = gameMin > gameScores[gameCounter - 1] ? gameScores[gameCounter - 1] : gameMin
  gameMax = gameMax < gameScores[gameCounter - 1] ? gameScores[gameCounter - 1] : gameMax
  gameAverage += (gameScores[gameCounter - 1] / NUMBER_OF_GAMES);
}
```

the `?` is an operator in c# to write quick if statements like I did above.

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

However in your code you could also clean up the for loop definitions as this:

```
for (int gameCounter = 0; gameCounter < gameScores.Length; gameCounter++)
```

When not adding 1 here you don't have to substract the 1 later

Also the best practice for comparing strings is using `.equals()`
as this:

```
bowler.Equals("Y")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help i appriciate it

Comment: @Joshua you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper-left of their answer.

Answer (score 0):

loop thru the games just like you did for average but just before you loop, have a variable like `minScore` or `maxScore` that you initialize to 1 or something. And then in the loop just check if the score is less or greater than the min or max. If it is, update the min/max.

Something like this:

```
int min = gameScores[0]; 
for (int gameCounter = 1; gameCounter < gameScores.Length + 1; gameCounter++)
{
    if (gameScores[gameCounter] < min)
        min = gameScores[gameCounter];
}
```

Comment: I think you mean just `gameCounter < gameScores.Length` in your loop? Otherwise you'll go out of bounds every time

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @DStanley, I just copied the code from the OP's question which does `+1` because they start their loop at `1`. But yes, if you start at `0` (like most people), you are correct.